# Properly setting up NCurses (curses.h) on VSCode Mac

Tags: c++, macos, ncurses

Omg I might be really dumb but I can't wrap my head around how am I supposed to properly link <curses.h> to my file. I've searched a lot but I don't seem to find information that helps.
Here's my code, a really basic one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curses.h>
#include <panel.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    initscr();

    WINDOW *p = newwin(0, 0, LINES / 2, COLS / 2);
    PANEL *p_panel = new_panel(p);
    waddstr(p, "that's what i'm talking about!");

    update_panels(); 
    doupdate(); 
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

I installed ncurses library with brew through terminal and i have an updated version of clang. Im trying to run an app in VSCode terminal. Here's the error i'm getting:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_COLS", referenced from:
      _main in lab8-80f309.o
  "_LINES", referenced from:
      _main in lab8-80f309.o
  "_doupdate", referenced from:
      _main in lab8-80f309.o
  "_endwin", referenced from:
      _main in lab8-80f309.o
  "_initscr", referenced from:
      _main in lab8-80f309.o
  "_new_panel", referenced from:
      _main in lab8-80f309.o
  "_newwin", referenced from:
      _main in lab8-80f309.o
  "_update_panels", referenced from:
      _main in lab8-80f309.o
  "_waddnstr", referenced from:
      _main in lab8-80f309.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried to link it manually using gcc, I used this command:
`clang++ lab8.cpp -lpanel -lncurses`
and same with g++.
It executed succesfully, file "a.out" was created but did no difference
I've also seen somewhere that I might need to link this library in tasks.json but I haven't found any examples and I have no idea. Any help could be great

Comment: Did you not try `gcc lab8.cpp  -lncurses -lpanel`?

Comment: Also c++ code should be compiled using `g++` not `gcc`

Comment: i tried all of these and with g++ too, commands execute with no error, but i get the same error compiling the program

Comment: You should use use `g++ lab8.cpp  -lpanel -lncurses`. Please post **only** output of **this** command. Remove output of all other commands, they are wrong and their output is not interesting in the sligtest and misleads those who are trying to help you.

Comment: check again, this command executes succesfully but I’m getting the same error that i posted while running the program

Comment: "this command executes succesfully but I’m getting the same error that i posted while running the program" No, this cannot happen. These errors are given by the compiler, not by your program. You are misinterpreting what actually happens. Most likely you are not running your program. You need to run it using `./a.out`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always a good idea to consult [the documentation](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/). Looking at the Section 2.1 shows that `-lncurses` is required for a very basic ncurses program, but there was nothing about panels there. Scrolling down the TOC to find panels leads to section 16.2 where it clearly shows that `-lpanel -lncurses` is required.

gcc and g++ are just aliases to LLVM on a Mac by default. `clang++ lab8.cpp -lpanel -lncurses` should do the trick just fine.

With a Mac and a brew installed ncurses, it again helps to read the documentation. In this case, you just need `brew info ncurses`. It clearly states:

```
For compilers to find ncurses you may need to set:
  set -gx LDFLAGS "-L/usr/local/opt/ncurses/lib"
  set -gx CPPFLAGS "-I/usr/local/opt/ncurses/include"
```

Running those commands should allow you to compile your brew ncurses. Conversely, the quoted strings can be added to your compile command.

`clang++ lab8.cpp "-I/usr/local/opt/ncurses/include" "-L/usr/local/opt/ncurses/lib" -lpanel -lncurses`

The above command was tested using the basic panels code from the documentation link above, and it works on my MacBook Pro using ncurses installed from brew.

This is also where I recommend a build system to automate this for you. Depending on how trivial your program is, a homespun makefile might be sufficient, but this seems like a great time to learn cmake.

---

It's worth pointing out that your code will do nothing. It makes the panel, then the program immediately ends. Whatever you drew will not simply stay on the screen.

Again, referencing the documentation shows that the line `getch();` before `endwin();` will 'freeze' the program so that you can see your text. Pressing any key should then end your program.

I should note that I made one other change to your example code, which may or may not apply to your overall project. If you are including `panel.h`, you don't need to include `ncurses.h`, and you never needed `iostream` in the example. So I only had `#include <panel.h>`.

Comment: That didn't work :( Getting the same error i posted, "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_COLS", referenced from:..." and on

Comment: Works just fine for me in WSL compiling the basic panels code in the documentation. There's something going on that's Mac/brew-specific.

Comment: @fvllenleaves Please see if the update addresses your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the update, Im pretty sure i ran these command before. Am i supposed to run clang++ command everytime running the program instead of the standart F5? I run it with no errors, but I'm not getting any output.

Comment: @fvllenleaves Please see my latest update. It addresses the fact that your code is now the problem. As far as those commands go, "pretty sure" is meaningless.

Comment: @fvllenleaves You have not set up your VSCode to run commands you want *and* you do not know what commands you want. Tackle one problem at a time. Shut down VSCode, open a terminal, and work from there. Once you figure out how to compile and run your program, return to VSCode and figure out how to make it compile and run your program for you, using commands you have figured out at the previous stage. VSCode is not very smart and it will not do what you want until you explain it *exactly*, and in order to explain it what to do *you need to know* what to do.

Comment: Sorry if i wasnt clear, I ran the commands again of course. I was a little confused about running the program, thanks a lot for your help. I just didnt realize that i had to manually compile and then run the "a.out".. i will work on the code now